# Boostrap card-deck is transparent and not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried to fix this issue for a long time now and can't seem to figure it out!
Please ignore the other language and the other code :) the card is under the jumbotron
(remove spaces for link - i have no idea how to post it otherwise)
https://code pen.io/anon/pen/vQqdoR

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect that you'd include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You'll get a much quicker solution this way.

Comment: So please remove everything that is not necessary to show your issue. Also, please correct the codepen link. There's an extra space in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Cards are new to bootstrap 4 and you're using the 3.7 cdn in your code pen. Updating to bootstrap version 4+ should fix your issues.